# How to use calburn micro to get implementation for an interface

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

How can I use Caliburn Micro to get the implementatio for an intrface? Something such as this:

```
   IMyClass myClass=App.BootStrapper.GetInstance(IMyClass)
```

which would return an instance of an implementation of IMyClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
IMyClass myClass= Caliburn.Micro.IoC.Get<IMyClass >();
```

But as you know, you should not do this and use constructor injection or property injection instead. But it is good to test if the IoC can detect and resolve the instance.